# XCode 4.5.2: Cannot run on the selected destination - Facebook SDK

Tags: xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Cannot run on the selected destination

The selected destination does not support the architecture for which the selected software is built.  Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software.

[image: Cannot run on the selected destination]

I am using the Facebook-iOS-SDK from GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk
tested latest commit (2a030e795aed343e7614e149a5ebdfa78b223a72) and sdk-version-3.0.8 tag, both having the same problem. Tested the Hackbook, Scrumptious, FriendPickerSample on both iDevices and iSimulator.

It was working before (on older version of XCode), so it could be the xcode upgrade, but my other projects work fine. I've tried multiple solutions on this site which works for others but not on mine, does anyone encounter this before with Facebook-SDK specifically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it seems like this is a bug on XCode, it will build and run fine for once every couple of restarts and with the entire project directory moved to other path. This is very sad because apple always make good products for consumer but all their developer software are crappy compared to big M's

Comment: i am facing same problem how you managed it to run? i want to run this.

Comment: it still doesn't run occasionally.
I downloaded iPhone 5.1 Simulator and it fail lesser on that

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** I have found the issue, if you install the FacebookSDK and you add the resources folder to get the facebook image buttons there is a Info.plist file. XCodes goes weird with this info.plist file. I have deleted it, made a clean and now it works perfect :)

**OLD:**
The same behavior here. On another projects it runs perfectly but in this one I have always the same problem. After some XCode restarts sometimes it runs ok, sometimes I "click" on run and then nothings happens, sometimes it runs...

The best option is to move the project to other path. Adding and removing the libsql3.0 from lib dependencies sometimes works too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. It seemed to start right after XCode hung and I had to force quit. This was a day before the 4.6 update. I hoped that that update might fix the problem. And I did get one successful build before I started getting that message (actually in 4.6 there are two different but similar messages that seem to alternate.

I solve the problem by letting XCode update the project settings. I first noticed this possibility when I made a duplicate copy of my project and open that, but it is clear that this option is also available in the original. Here is what I did

In the Issues Navigator just under my project "MyProject project" I had a message MyProject.xcode
  Validate Project Settings
  Update to recommended settings.

I click on that and I was presented with a dialog box with 4 checkboxes some explanatory text and the option to perform changes. I just let Xcode make those changes and everything has been fine since.

Answer (score 0):

Remove info.plist from Facebook Resources folder. Changed the location of XCode project and Reset the iPhone simulator...now it is working :) Buggy XCode !!